# OnMouseOver pause or stop the setTimeOut function

Tags: javascript

Hi I have twitter bootstrap alert here, wherein I implemented a duration/delay and after 1 second it disappears...

But i want to accomplish is that when I hover the flash alert, the setTimeOut pauses for a while or stops.

Here is my js file:

```
var hideFlashes;

$(document).ready(function() {
  return setTimeout(hideFlashes, 1000);
});

hideFlashes = function() {
  return $(".alert").fadeOut(4000);
};
```

I am calling the div class `alert

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="info">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <p><strong>Oppcis Tips:</strong>
        You have the privileges to view, add, edit or delete specific agencies.
        </p>
    </div>
```

I really want to know how to `stop` a certain fading timer.

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(".alert").hover(function(){$(".alert").stop();});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea. I added mouseout value to continue the fadeOut function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Still thanks for ^ @drasick 's approach above..

Fork my gist: https://gist.github.com/4672970

for those who want the same approach as mine.

I used `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions

instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` or `hover`

https://gist.github.com/4672970